# How to add to project additional files not intended to be compiled?

Tags: intellij-idea, setup-project

I would like to add into project some files that shouldn't be compiled. I mean mainly text files with for example notes, concepts, comments etc.
I realized that it is possible only at module level. But it is not very convenient. I'd rather prefer to keep them on project level. Is it possible in any way?

And if not:
I have another idea: to create special module, name it for example "other_stuff", do not create src directory and put files there. Is it ok? I'm afraid of potential compilation problems when one of modules is artificial, with no sources but still has sdk assigned (it is probably impossible to leave module without sdk assigned).

Comment: Why isn't it convenient to add at the module level?  I didn't understand that.

Comment: If notes concerns whole project it is not natural to keep them in one of its modules. They are more difficult to find in project tree etc.

Answer (score 1):

While generating artifacts you can add any file into your artifact. Also, in modules you can have folders not declared as source, and they will not be compiled.